# How do I explain the different .NET versions to someone?

Tags: .net

My boss keeps asking me "which version of .NET are we upgrading to", to which I answer "3.5, the latest one".

But then he sees things about how .NET 3.5 is just a set of libraries on top of .NET 2.0 and I find myself having to explain it to him.

And of course the version of C# that ships with .NET 3.5 is actually C# 3.0.

What's a good way to explain the different versions of .NET to a non-techie type in a way that doesn't confuse them or freak them out?

Comment: While 3.5 is framework version, it needs language support (i.e. c# 3.0. use of linq expression is an example of language support)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should decompose .NET as a package of three different things:

1. CLR, the runtime
2. Libraries
3. Languages, compilers and tools

This way, it'll be pretty easier to explain.

For instance, in .NET 3.5 we have:

1. .NET CLR v2.0
2. v3.5 assemblies
3. C# 3.0 compiler

Answer (score 7):

And just to add to Mehrdad's list:

4) Admit the nomenclature is positively retarded, and is a good reason that Microsoft's DEVDIV should take the marketing department outside and shoot them.

-Oisin

Comment: It's not the worst thing on the planet... The worst was Windows .NET Server Family 2003 which was fortunately renamed to Windows Server 2003!

Comment: What about SharePoint 2001 WSS (Windows Storage System - the backing store element), then SharePoint 2003 WSS (Windows SharePoint Services, the whole product) ?

Comment: Longhorn still kicks the s**t outta "vista."  Feh.

Answer (score 1):

[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) gives a good overview in his book [C# in Depth - Chapter 1](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If I were to load the [.NET homepage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/default.aspx) and see all of the references to 3.5, I'd assume that was the most current version.

Maybe [this diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DotNet.svg) would help too

Comment: And your assumption would be correct.  .NET 3.5 is the latest version, currently.